# random variable is independent of any random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

How to prove this statement:

> ***random variable is independent of any random variable***

Comment: what is a degenerate random variable ?

Comment: I guess it's a "non random variable" meaning $X(\omega)$ doesn't depend on $\omega$ (and if it is so you just have to write the definition of independance)

Comment: Let's say that $X = a$ almost surely for some $a$.  Try starting with the definition: you need $P(X \in A, Y\in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$.  What happens if $a \in A$?  What happens if $a \notin A$?

Comment: @Ewan http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution

Comment: A degenerate random variable is constant with probability $1$, so it can't be dependent from any random variable

Comment: actually I have the same idea since let $x=0$ then $P(x=0)=1$ so should be independent, but i am still confused to prove that statement by mathematically/statistically.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a random variable, and let $Y$ be degenerate, taking on a single value $y_0$ with probability $1$. Then for any (measurable) sets $A$ and $B$ of reals, 
$$\Pr((X\in A)\cap (Y\in B))=\Pr(X\in A)\Pr(Y\in B),\tag{1}$$
since $\Pr(Y\in B)$ is $1$ or $0$, depending on whether $y_0\in B$ or $y_0\not\in B$.

If one wants **full* detail, there are two cases. If $y_0\in B$, then $\Pr((X\in A)\cap (Y\in B))=\Pr(X\in A)$, which is the same as the right-hand side of (1). And if $y_0\not\in B$, then both sides of (1) are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

A [degenerate random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) is one that is constantly one value. So $P(X = x^*) = 1$ and $P(X \neq x^*) = 0$, and similarly for continuous random variables.

Now, $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)$. In this case we trivially have:
$$
P\left((X = x^*) \cap Y\right) = 1*P(Y) = P(X)P(Y)\\
P\left((X \neq x^*) \cap Y\right) = 0*P(Y) = P(X)P(Y)
$$
So it is independent regardless of $Y$.